# CSRF token not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp

I am following a tutorial on spring security and I have the following so far:
I get following error when I try to login from my login page:

HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

The solution I found on stackoverflow indicated to add a hidden attribute to the form and I did that. this is the attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="{_csrf.token}"/>
```

I have rechecked the code multiple times to and I keep getting the same 403 error even though my code seems to exactly match the Udemy tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

My login.jsp page:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Please login</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <c:url value="/login" var="loginProcessingUrl"/>
 <form action="${loginProcessingUrl}" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Login</legend>
        <!-- use param.error assuming FormLoginConfigurer#failureUrl contains the query parameter error -->
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <div>
                Failed to login.
                <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                  Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <!-- the configured LogoutConfigurer#logoutSuccessUrl is /login?logout and contains the query param logout -->
        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
            <div>
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        </p>
        <!-- if using RememberMeConfigurer make sure remember-me matches RememberMeConfigurer#rememberMeParameter -->
        <p>
        <label for="remember-me">Remember Me?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me"/>

        </p>


        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="{_csrf.token}"/>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
        </div>


    </fieldset>

 </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

My index.jsp with a logout form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <c:url value="/showMessage.html" var="messageUrl" />
        <a href="${messageUrl}">Click to enter</a>

        <form action="logout" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="logout"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="{_csrf.token}"/>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My security config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void congigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

An Empty WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

A login controller:

```
    @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(ModelMap map){

        //prefix: /WEB-INF/view
        //postfix .jsp
        //prefix + view + postfix
        // /WEB-INF/view/login.jsp
        return "login";

    }
```

This is the code in my application-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.springsecurityexample"/>
```

This is the code in my mvc-config.xml file:

```
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.springsecurityexample.web"/> 


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

and my web.xml file:

```
<display-name>SpringSecurityTut1</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: As far as I know about Java config, dont you have to add the CSRF token parameter in your  public void configure method.

Comment: In the video, the tutor did not. How would you do tht though. i am willing to try it.

Comment: Check out Spring-security documentation rather than complaining that the tutor didn't have it. Also the answer given by wpj below is correct.

Comment: I did check out the Spring docs and it had the same thing the tutor had. wpj's answer did not work and caused another problem once I fixed the real problem. The tutor's solution worked, so my observation about the tutor was valid. Anyway, it was a spelling error. I forgot the $ in my value assignment statement. And btw, I figured out how to add a CSRF token in the configure method and it worked. Nevertheless, it worked even without me adding the token. Seemingly, this is because Spring 4 and upwards automatically enables the token. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple mistake that cost me a whole day. I forgot the "$" in my value assignment in both the login and index page.

I had value="{_csrf.token}
instead of value="${_csrf.token}

That was it. A missing dollar sign!! Thanks for all the input people.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need `<form:form></form:form>`
because

```
 <input type="hidden"
               name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
               value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

is spring'tag

Comment: I tried that and the message changed from:
HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?
So I am still stuck.
To:

HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token '{_csrf.token}' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Comment: An omission caused the original problem. I left out the second $. Once I fixed the omission error, using <form:form></form:form> seemed to cause my onClick event not to register. In spite of this correcting the omission fixed my original problem. Thanks for your input.